# How to create a Font Family package with Lerna monorepo for Vue and Angular projects?

Tags: javascript, font-family, monorepo, lerna, npm-package

Working on a private npm custom package to apply a specific Font Family to Vue2 and Angular repos. I have created Vue component packages before but never for "frame-work agnostic" features and Fonts are also quite particular.

Here it the file structure

[Here it the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R58PK.png)

And here is the code...

fonts.scss : Unsure the `@font-face` is the best approach

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Effra';
    src: url('./assets/Effra-Italic_1.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Effra';
    src: url('./assets/EffraHeavy-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    ...
}...
```

index.js

```
import './fonts.scss'  // do not think I am importing correctly

const Fonts = () => {
    const app = document.body;
    app.style.fontFamily = 'Effra', sans-serif;
}

export default Fonts
```

package.json  : what dependecies will I need?

```
{
    "name": "@company/fonts",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "description": "company fonts",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "files": [
        "src/*"
    ],
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://bitbucket.org/company/repo.git"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions"
    ]
}
```

Do I need a `node_modules` file?

Note: I do not have publishing rights.

Thanks a lot!